# If $g: A \to B$ is a morphism of algebras over a ring $R$, then $\ker(B\otimes_R B \to B\otimes_A B) = \langle\{g(a)\otimes 1 - \otimes g(a)\}\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

It is easy to show that, for $B \otimes_R B \to B$ the result follows, by writing
$$
\sum a\otimes b =  (a\otimes 1 - 1\otimes a)(1\otimes b) + (1\otimes ab).
$$
But, how to prove that for $B \otimes_R B \to B \otimes_A B$? Actually, to show that $ \langle\{g(a)\otimes 1 - \otimes g(a)\}\rangle \subseteq \ker(B\otimes_R B \to B\otimes_A B)$ is simple, but I could not show the other inclusion.

Any hint would be very appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think showing that there is a map from $B\otimes_A B\to B\otimes_R B/\langle\{ g(a)\otimes 1- 1\otimes g(a)\}\rangle$ that serves as the inverse of your map would work.

Comment: It is a good idea. I am going to try it out. Thank you!